# Effect of the curse of dimension on collision detection

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I require a crude intersection analyzer or collision detector in about 15 dimensions. I am wondering if such a function is rendered difficult or impossible by the "curse of dimension". Collision detectors are widely used in 2 and 3 dimensions to determine if two shapes are in contact. A function that determines the intersection of two regions is one way to make a collision detector. The "curse of dimension" refers to difficulties encountered as the number of dimensions involved increases beyond about 5. For example, all points tend to be clustered near hyper-surfaces, and, statistically, all points behave like outliers. (See the [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimension).) I haven't been able to find any literature on such collision detectors beyond 4 dimensions, and I would appreciate being pointed in the right (best?) direction.

Answer (score 11):

An overview of high-dimensional collision detection for the purpose of motion planning is in [Petrović - Motion planning in high-dimensional spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07457):

> Grid-based approaches are resolution complete and often offer optimal
> solutions. However, the number of grid points grows exponentially in
> the configuration space dimension, which makes even the
> state-of-the-art methods inappropriate for very high-dimensional
> problems. Sampling-based approaches are efficient in most practical
> problems but offer weaker guarantees. They are probabilistically
> complete, however, they often require post-processing and can still be
> inefficient in very complex configuration spaces. Trajectory
> optimization approaches can solve high-dimensional motion planning
> problems quickly, but solutions are only locally optimal.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If your objects fit into ellipsoids, then one option might be the [Perram-Wertheim distance](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999185901718); in dimension $n$ you do need to invert an $n \times n$ matrix, which might be do-able ...

Comment: Yes, I'll always be on machines with programmable GPUs, and matrix inversion is one of their strengths. Thanks, this is just what I need.